# Fail to load pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I can't connect to server. Using `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d mydb` and pgAdmin, in both case:

psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I changed the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'

host    all             postgres        0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

When I restart the service:

```
2019-05-03 18:04:01 -03 [23773-1] LOG:  peer authentication is only supported on local sockets
2019-05-03 18:04:01 -03 [23773-2] CONTEXT:  line 92 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf"
2019-05-03 18:04:01 -03 [23773-3] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

### Update

I already change md5 to peer.

```
92  host    all     all         127.0.0.1/32    peer
93  host    all     postgres    0.0.0.0/0       md5
```

ps -ef | grep post

```
thiago  3583 21771  0 09:04 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto post
root     24726  8345  0 Mai03 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo -i -u postgres
postgres 24727 24726  0 Mai03 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
```

Comment: what is line 92 of the configuration file?

Comment: As the error message says, you can't use "peer" with "host", only with "local".  If you already changed md5 to peer, then change peer back to md5, or to some other method that works with "host".

Comment: After you restart, has the service actually come up - what's the output of `ps -ef | grep post`?  You can always edit your own questions. Try logging in without the 127..... Can you su to the postgres user? Have you tried just logging in as yourself - i.e. no `-U`? Try leaving out the database as well - if you can get in at all, you might be able to `\c` to other databases. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I updated my question. But this line was already created, I just added 93.

Comment: @jjanes I used peer, md5 and trust, changed all to postgres.

Comment: Thank you guys, I could solve it!!! Revised the line 92, take it out and works..